CSS negative margins, why overlapping on background not in content
When applying a negative margin to an element why the text 1 over the background of child 2 and behind the text, I thought it will be behind the whole box.


html {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.child1 {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}

.child2 {
  color: black;
  background-color: green;
  margin: -35px 0 0 20px;
}
<div>
  <div class="child1">text 1 some text here</div>
  <div class="child2">text 2 other text here</div>
</div>




@marc_s why remove the inline snippet?

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
  html {
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .child1 {
    color: white;
    background-color: red;
    position: relative; /* Create stacking context */
    z-index: 2; /* Ensure it is above .child2 */
  }

  .child2 {
    color: black;
    background-color: green;
    margin: -35px 0 0 20px;
    position: relative; /* Ensure it is part of stacking context */
    z-index: 1; /* Ensure it is below .child1 */
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  <div>
    <div class="child1">text 1 some text here</div>
    <div class="child2">text 2 other text here</div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>


Add an explanation for your code. Never just dump a chuck of code and expect that everyone will know what it is that you did. See [answer]

I don't search for the solution, i wanted to understand the browser behaviour, in fact the question's answer helped me alot.
